# ¿Porque mi DataGridView no muestra valores?

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net, datatables, datagrid, datagridview

Estoy haciendo una aplicación de Visual Basic con Windows Forms que contiene varios DataGridView, sin embargo, hay uno que me da problemas, concretamente estoy recuperando valores de dos tablas para mostrar unos valores concretos de una tabla concreta de forma manual en el DataGridView a través de un DataSet que contiene un DataTable, y efectivamente, a la hora de mostrarlo me muestra la tabla en el DataGridView, pero con las celdas vacías, he probado de todo, pero no veo como hacer que se muestren los valores, adjunto el código y un pantallazo del resultado con el fallo, seguramente sea una tontería, pero no soy capaz de verlo.

```
Public idpul As Integer
    Public idrestcooV As String
    Dim idrestcootable As DataTable
    Dim restcoo As DataTable
    Dim cacheRow As DataRow
    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        idrestcootable = New DataTable("idrestcoo")
        restcoo = New DataTable("restcoo")

        restcoo.Columns.Add("Coordenadas")
        restcoo.Columns.Add("Radio (M)")
        restcoo.Columns.Add("idrestcoo")

        CacheDataSet.Tables.Add(restcoo)

        idpul = PulTableAdapter1.QueryIdpulDNI(UserControl41.ComboBox1.Text)
        idrestcootable = RelpulrestTableAdapter1.GetDataByIdPul(idpul).CopyToDataTable

        If idrestcootable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            For i As Integer = 0 To (idrestcootable.Rows.Count - 1)
                If i >= 0 Then
                    idrestcooV = idrestcootable.Rows(i).Item(1)
                    cacheRow = restcoo.NewRow
                    cacheRow("Coordenadas") = i 'estoy usando la variable i para rellenar las celdas con algún dato, de forma provisional, para no usar datos reales.
                    cacheRow("Radio (M)") = i
                    cacheRow("idrestcoo") = i
                    restcoo.Rows.Add(cacheRow)
                End If
            Next
        End If

        DataGridView1.DataSource = CacheDataSet.Tables("restcoo").DefaultView

        GpsdirTableAdapter1.Fill(Me.IsafetrackDataSetP.gpsdir, idpul)

    End Sub
```

Esto es lo que pasa, muestra las celdas correspondientes, pero sin datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puede ser porque estas añadiendo la tabla `restcoo` a `CacheDataSet` antes de meter los datos en la propia tabla

Comment: he probado a ponerlo después, pero el problema no se soluciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya he resuelto el problema, lo que he hecho ha sido asignar la tabla al DataSet desde el diseñador de visual Studio, adjunto imágenes del proceso:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

una vez asignado desde el diseñador, he eliminado la creación de la tabla y las columnas mediante código, quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        idrestcootable = New DataTable("idrestcoo")

        idpul = PulTableAdapter1.QueryIdpulDNI(UserControl41.ComboBox1.Text)
        idrestcootable = RelpulrestTableAdapter1.GetDataByIdPul(idpul).CopyToDataTable

        If idrestcootable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            For i As Integer = 0 To (idrestcootable.Rows.Count - 1)
                If i >= 0 Then
                    idrestcooV = idrestcootable.Rows(i).Item(1)
                    RestcooTableAdapter1.Fill(Me.IsafetrackDataSetP.restcoo, idrestcooV)
                    cacheRow = restcoo.NewRow
                    cacheRow("Coordenadas") = RestcooTableAdapter1.restcoord(idrestcooV)
                    cacheRow("RadioMetros") = RestcooTableAdapter1.restradio(idrestcooV)
                    cacheRow("idrestcoo") = idrestcooV
                    restcoo.Rows.Add(cacheRow)
                End If
            Next
        End If

        GpsdirTableAdapter1.Fill(Me.IsafetrackDataSetP.gpsdir, idpul)

    End Sub
```

unan vez hecho esto, he compilado y ejecutaod y ha empezado a mostrar los datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mil gracias a todos por vuestra ayuda :)